# PDO give Mysql Error 1146

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-error-1146

```
    $deleteID = $_POST['oz'];
    if(!$deleteID){
        echo '2';
        die;    
    } else {
        //It should be working.
    }
    $checkVar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user_posts` WHERE `id`=:delete");
    $checkVar->bindValue(':delete',$deleteID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($checkVar->execute() == false){
        echo '2';
        die;
    }
```

I'm really pissed off. $deleteID is supplied, nothing is being binded. Why not, please someone help.

Comment: Okay, `$deleteID is supplied`, what about $my_id?

Comment: Yes, that's supplied in server.php. I included a specific amount of code. I removed a ton of code in this thread and just included the main stuff.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong?  Are you getting an error message?  What is the error?

Comment: It echoes '2'; which only echos out when it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly is happening? No result? Wrong data? An error in the query? Have you checked for errors? Have you switched on query logging in the database and checked what query is being executed exactly? You being pissed off is not a problem description that helps us solve your issue.

Comment: @Jake it also `echo`s 2 when the `$deleteID` is empty or if the user isn't an admin (per your previous, longer code sample). Are you sure that it's even reaching the SQL?

Comment: Not really relevant, but why are you binding a PDO::PARAM_STR instead of int? and please answer @AgentConundrum 's question

Comment: @AgentConundrum I added that in afterwards, i've been changing these variables too. This runs through an ajax script, and yes it reaches the server. 1 = Success, 2 = You don't have permission. I made it afterwards if you don't have the value, just say it's not permitted since it's not deleted.

Also I'm just used to put STR. Should change it to INT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. make PDO to throw exception on error,
   `$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`
   after connect.
2. Make sure you can see errors occurred, either in logs or on the screen.
3. Run **the very code** you posted here, **not** some other code. As in the other code there can be other errors, irrelevant to your binding problem.

For the `Table doesn't exist` problem you have to check for mistakes like typos, letter case, wrong server connected, wrong PHP file edited etc. Say, you are running your PHPMyAdmin against localhost while actual script against remote host or something of the kind.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'web-xpherio_db2.user_posts' doesn't exist' in /home/blah->


But. The table does exist: http://i.imgur.com/nC1S78e.png

Comment: @Jake Does the user account you're using in your PHP code have permission to modify that table?

Comment: Yes. There is one user account. And it also an administrator, so after this check it'll say "Is this user an admin?" and if it is, it voids that check and continues the script anyways.

Answer (score 2):

If it says the table does not exist the table does not exist.

You either connect to the wrong server, select the wrong database or you have a case problem.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

> [..] Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names. This means such names are not case sensitive in Windows, but are case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

Make sure you are connecting to the same database and server you are currently looking at

```
print_r( $pdo );
```

This is Not an authorization issue.

One more advice. If you are pissed off, take a break, drink a tea, calm down, then read 'Your common sense' excellent answer and watch at your code again :)